# Something like "object-fit: cover" for CylinderGeometry three.js when using THREE.VideoTexture();

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I would really like to have something like this:

[image: Glass Jar with checker background]

Where the checkered background is the texture, and the jar is a cylinder with the texture on it like so.

I really don't know too much about three.js, so I am not sure about exactly what information I have to give. I am using THREE.OrthographicCamera, if that helps! Also, I have to use THREE.VideoTexture() for this.

What I Originally Did:

```
var material = THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
//material-related stuff here
   map: new THREE.VideoTexture(video)
});
```

What I Got:

[image]

What I want(With a cylinder instead of a sphere):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just applying the texture to the `.map` material property?

```
var geom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5, 5, 20, 32);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "textures/checkered.jpg" )
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
```

Comment: Btw I did not put this in but I am using THREE.VideoTexture(), I will make an edit for that. When I simply put THREE.VideoTexture() for the map parameter, the entire texture will go onto the image.

Comment: Wait, so you want to use a VideoTexture as the background, and you want to refract that background with the cylinder?

Comment: Yes, I think that this is what I am aiming for

Comment: [Here's an example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_balls_refraction.html) of refraction, and [here's a second one](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction.html). Although they use a cubemap as an environment map to calculate the refractions. I'm not sure that Three.js can use a flat background, but maybe you could set your VideoTexture to [Scene.environment](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Scene.environment) and see if it works?